# Properties within a single chart on a topological manifold and smoothness

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Reading on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Topological_manifolds) it is stated that

> A topological manifold looks locally like a Euclidean space in a
> rather weak manner: while for each individual chart it is possible to
> distinguish differentiable functions or measure distances and angles,
> merely by virtue of being a topological manifold a space does not have
> any particular and consistent choice of such concepts.[7]

Within a single chart, is there a well-defined concept of distance? Further, if this is the case, what other structures, that would otherwise be traditionally be added to a topological manifold, like a symplectic structure, is present in a single chart?

As a second question, I am trying to understand exactly what goes wrong for performing calculus when the transition maps of a manifold are not smooth? i.e what exactly does the smoothness of transition maps bring?

[7] Kervaire, M. (1961). "A Manifold which does not admit any differentiable structure". Comment. Math. Helv. 35 (1): 1–14. doi:10.1007/BF02565940. S2CID 120977898.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you fix a chart, you can define distances between points to just be the distances in Euclidean space between the images, under the chart maps, of those points. But this is rather silly, since a pair of points may lie in several charts, may correspond to entirely different points in Euclidean space under the chart maps, and thus have very different distances depending on which chart you decide to use. This silliness is what your quote means by "not have any particular and consistent choice". Every chart has its own opinion about what distances should be, what differentiability should mean, etc.

Smoothness of transition maps makes the charts agree as to what differentiability should mean. That's essential for getting a consistent calculus on the manifold (as opposed to a cacophony of opinions from all the charts).

But even having smooth transition maps isn't enough to get a consistent notion of distance. That needs additional structure on the manifold, like a Riemannian metric.